# How can i get nested responsed values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If i getting this via ajax with `dataType = 'JSON'`:

```
[{"extras": {"tags": "[<Tag: tag1>, <Tag: tag2>]"}}]
```

How can i create links like this:

```
<a href="tag/ + value.extras.tags.tag1">tag1</a>
<a href="tag/ + value.extras.tags.tag2">tag2</a>
```

?

Comment: You sure you want the href to literally be `tag/ + value.extras.tags.tag1`, or did you want that to be `tag/tag1`?

Comment: That's not a "true" JSON object -- the double-quotes around the brackets and the <...> instead of {...} mean you'll have to write your own parser.

Comment: `tag/tag1` is that what i looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tags = data[0].extras.tags.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(', ');
$.each(tags, function(i,v){
  var tag = v.match(/<Tag:\s(.*)>/);
  if(tag !== null){
    var href = 'tag/';
    // <a href="tag/tag1">tag1</a>
    var $link = $('<a/>').attr('href', href+tag[1]).text(tag[1]);
    $('#myDiv').append($link);
  }
});
```

Note: I suggest you follow @jfriend00's advice, and change the structure of your JSON.  I'll leave this here anyway, as it works with the data you have.

Comment: But how can i add this links to example `div`? After `  var $link = $('<a/>').attr('href', href+tag[1]).text(tag[1]);` i try `$('div').append($link)` and `alert($link)` but i get `$link is not defined` So if i need to append every $link to div after $link is specified how can i do it?

Comment: @Cris: `$('#myDiv').append($link)` should work.  I tested this code, and the `console.log($link)` works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON data doesn't make any sense to me.  You've basically got this:

```
jsonObj[0].extras.tags
```

as a string value that is equal to this:

```
"[<Tag: tag1>, <Tag: tag2>]"
```

So, to make any sense of that string, it would have to be parsed manually and it's unclear from your question what exactly you want out of this string to be created into the tags.

What I would suggest is that you put the actual data you want into it's own JSON values rather than put the meat of your data all in one string that then needs to be parsed again.

If you want to clarify the question, we can perhaps help more.

Based on other comments, I think you want your JSON to be this so there is no manual parsing required and all data goes into actual javascript objects:

```
[{"extras": {"tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]}}]
```

Then, you can do a loop like this to access the tag values:

```
var tagArray = jsonObj[0].extras.tags;
for (var i = 0; i < tagArray.length; i++) {
    var tagVal = tagArray[i];
    // do what you want here with tagVal
}
```

If that first array in your JSON can have multiple elements to it and you want to see all of them, then you can iterate through them too:

```
var tagArray;
for (var j = 0; j < jsonObj.length; j++) {
    tagArray = jsonObj[j].extras.tags;
    for (var i = 0; i < tagArray.length; i++) {
        var tagVal = tagArray[i];
        // do what you want here with tagVal
    }
}
```

Comment: I added some more to my answer to explain how you would revise your JSON to eliminate manual parsing.

Comment: Hmm... Chrome said `tags` is undefined.

Comment: You see, it is because of my poor js, i haven't specified jsonOjb, i think. Thank You for help.

Comment: jsonObj is what I assign the JSON to in my test code.  If you are loading this from the server, the JSON data should be a parameter to the success function of your ajax call and you would use the name of that parameter to reference it.  We could help you better on this topic if you put the ajax code in your question.

Comment: Everything now is fine. Thank You.